# How to subset vector based on string character?

Tags: string, r

I have a vector composed of entries such as "ZZZ1Z01Z0ZZ0", "1001ZZ0Z00Z0", and so on, and I want to subset this vector based on conditions such as:

1. The third character is a Z
2. The third AND seventh characters are Z
3. The third AND seventh characters are Z, AND none of the other characters are Z

I tried playing around with strsplit and grep, but I couldn't figure out a way to restrict my conditions based on the position of the character on the string. Any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: Will the vectors always have the same length and only 0, 1s and Z? I don't know how this stuff works, I only might be able to give a regex for it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with regular expressions (see `?regexp` for details on regular expressions).

`grep` returns the location of the match and returns a zero-length vector if no match is found.  You may want to use `grepl` instead, since it returns a logical vector you can use to subset.

```
z <- c("ZZZ1Z01Z0ZZ0", "1001ZZ0Z00Z0")
# 3rd character is Z ("^" is start of string, "." is any character)
grep("^..Z", z)
# 3rd and 7th characters are Z
grep("^..Z...Z", z)
# 3rd and 7th characters are Z, no other characters are Z
# "[]" defines a "character class" and "^" in a character class negates the match
# "{n}" repeats the preceding match n times, "+" repeats is one or more times
grep("^[^Z]{2}Z[^Z]{3}Z[^Z]+", z)
```

Comment: And why would you even consider doing it any other way?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've started playing around with regular expressions and they are **awesome**! Can't believe I hadn't bumped into this before. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Expanding Josh's answer, you want

```
your_dataset <- data.frame(
  z = c("ZZZ1Z01Z0ZZ0", "1001ZZ0Z00Z0")
)
regexes <- c("^..Z", "^..Z...Z", "^[^Z]{2}Z[^Z]{3}Z[^Z]+")

lapply(regexes, function(rx)
{
  subset(your_dataset, grepl(rx, z))
})
```

Also consider replacing `grepl(rx, z)` with `str_detect(z, rx)`, using the `stringr` package.  (There's no real difference except for slightly more readable code.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the first two without regular expressions using the substr command to pull out specific characters if you want.

```
# Grab the third character in each element and compare it to Z
substr(z, 3, 3) == "Z"
# Check if the 3rd and 7th characters are both Z
(substr(z, 3, 3) == "Z") & (substr(z, 7, 7) == "Z")
```

However, the regular expression approach Joshua gave is more flexible and trying to implement the third restriction you had using a substr approach would be a pain.  Regular expressions are much more well suited for a problem like your third restriction and learning how to use them is never a bad idea.